# Using moskito with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, health-monitoring

I am trying to use the [moskito](http://www.moskito.org/) tool to monitor a spring boot based application. Not having done this before, I am trying to follow the documentation and I've got my pom.xml with these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-webui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This much does not seem enough; from what I read it should have brought up the webUI at http://localhost:8080/mui but I'm just getting a generic Spring Boot error page with nothing in the console. Has anyone tried to make these two work together?

Comment: Are you following the aop approach? http://www.moskito.org/integration.html#section-aop

Comment: Well I am trying to use the Monitor annotation. I am trying to figure out how to expose the metrics - referring to https://confluence.opensource.anotheria.net/display/MSK/MoSKito-Control+Quick+Setup+Guide it looked like I just needed to add the dependency but does not work by default with spring boot. There is a web-fragment.xml defined in the moskito-inspect-remote jar - how do I get spring boot to use this?

Comment: And then I found this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2175 that may answer why this is not working. Still not very sure how to fix it.

Comment: Hello,
maybe you should redefine the question a little. 1) does your spring boot application work without moskito? 2) which version of moskito do you use? because since 2.5 the default url is moskito-inspect.